# Anguarjs: Changing a controller variable by an asynchronous service method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have declared an empty list in a controller that need to be updated by the callback of a method from a service:

```
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, appService) {
  var list = [];
   appService.sMethod().then(function(result){
     list = result;
   });
    console.log(list);
  })
```

the method from the service is asynchronous:

```
.service('appService', function($timeout){
  return {
    sMethod: function(ctrlVar){
      return $timeout(function(){
        return ['response'];
      })
    }
  }
})
```

You can try it here: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/rKoLBj

Apparently it doesn't work. I know, there is a scoping issue. Tried with `.bind(this)` and assigning `self = this` but cannot get it work. At first I thought it is because it's updated asynchronously but looking at browsers console it doesn't show the updated object even after the callback is executed.

Any solution to this?

Comment: appService.sMethod().then(function(result){
     list = result; console.log(list);
   });  This will print your list  https://codepen.io/SehaxX/pen/aKPBLm?editors=1111

Comment: This [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKqNrX#anon-signup) seems to be working fine.

Comment: @SehaxX i need the list outside the callback

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS I don't need the list in $scope, but a wrapper probably would resolve.

Comment: @neptune https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call